# How can i Prove that the gray area is the same as white area?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles, area

A circle is cut into 8 parts, each part has the angle 45 degrees from an arbitrary point. how to prove that the white area is the same as the Gray area?
[image: Circle cut into 8 parts]

I just want any hint for solving this question. how can I prove this?

Comment: The area of a triangle with respect to given two sides $a,b$ and angle between the sides is $0.5 a b \sin \theta$ s.t $\theta$ is the angle between the two sides can you proceed ?

Comment: This is the Pizza Theorem. See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/581895/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/865818/42969

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Carter and Wagon's proof without words:

[image]

(Image author: Christian Lawson-Perfect, [source](https://www.geogebra.org/m/C9kMuwj8))

Comment: Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 5):

This theorem is known as the Pizza theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem for further reading). There exist algebraic proofs, but the most elegant proof for the 8 segment case is below:
[image]

In general, alternating areas are equal iff the number of segments is a multiple of 4 at least 8.

Comment: How are segments counted?  If this is eight from the concurrence point, then four will not work.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Sorry about that, I've fixed my answer.