# About a short proof of Pizza Theorem

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I met the Pizza theorem today after this link activated several years later: [Proof of the Pizza Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581895/proof-of-the-pizza-theorem)

Then I searched it with Google and found a very short proof made by calculus:
[https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper57.pdf](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Emikeh/webpapers/paper57.pdf)

I understood the proof except the area formula. I have some scepticism. Why is the area formula $$\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\frac{1}{2}r(\theta)^2d\theta$$ is still valid although the point $P$ is not the center? Can somebody explain this? I couldn't.

Thanks before for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$r(\theta)$ is the radius from $P$ to the outside part of the pizza. The area of a small segment of the pizza subtending an angle $\delta\theta$ is the area of a triangle, the height times the base times a half. The height is $r(\theta)$ and the base is $r(\theta)\times\delta\theta$ since the base's length is proportional to the angle times the radius. So you get $$\frac12 r(\theta)^2\delta\theta.$$

The rest is just taking the limit as $\delta\theta$ becomes infinitessimal.

[image]

There is a [fuller discussion in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_.28area.29).

Comment: Thanks but what is the archlength? It depends on the position of $P$. I tired to compute it. It is complicated.

Comment: You don't need the arclength to compute the area.